# Material UI: not able to interact with the background elements when the MUI Dialog is open

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, responsive-design, frontend, styling

I'm working on a Chatbox styling using MUI and I've a issue. I'm not able to interacting with the background elements when the Dialog is open. I'm only able to click on the Dialog content but not able to click on the background Form Component.

herer is he codesandbox link :
https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-snowflake-jolyw7?file=/src/components/Chatbox.js

in the Console I Change the z-index to 1 it worked but not able to interact with the foreground component that is chatbox.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first close the modal then you would be able to make any changes in the background form.

Checked your code and found that outside click is not working the modal is is not hiding , with this you're unable to use the form.

change Dialog material UI to this :

```
 <Dialog
        disableScrollLock
        disableEnforceFocus
        hideBackdrop
        onClick={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title"
        open={open}
        transitionDuration={{ enter: 500, exit: 500 }}
        // scroll="body"
        sx={{
          paddingLeft: "50%"
        }}
      >
```

With this when you click in background form element , First the modal pop up will close and then you can make changes in the form.

Hope this helps !

Comment: it should not close on click anywhere is stay open untill use did not want to close I put the button the upper right. Either the Dialog box is open or not use will be able to fill the form. This is the scenario.
Thanks for helping this is my first Experience posting my question.

Comment: oh ok , i got what you are trying to do , basically when you open modal pop up and inspect it , it will take full screen , just the display part is what being displayed , we cannot access background elements with modal being open. for this to change we have to close the modal and then access the background elements. This is why i added a  code that when we click outside of modal popup the popup will first disappear and then we have access to the forms.
@ImranYasin